# Backup strategies for linux based file servers

Tags: backup, backup-restoration

I want to know some enterprise-wide backup strategies used for linux based file servers. What are the tools and techniques used when making a backup. for e.g when a backup fails on a machine, it should email the admin about the failure and also a log file. This won't happen incase the HDD fails and the system is completely out of work, but in other cases where a backup didn't take place, the admin should be able to know. What tool/scripts can be used for this particular scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

rsync!

or rather, rsnapshot  (which uses rsync)

Comment: does rsync email the admin in case of failures. A complete of tools would be helpful

Comment: rsync doesn't, since it's just a simple command.  rsnapshot, which is a backup tool does

Answer (score 0):

there are probably dozens of backup solutions for linux, the two that come to mind are `bacula` and `amanda` i don't personally have extensive experience with either, but they are both actively developed and more than likely have options for notification of failure.

barring that, you can easily roll your own backup solution using `rsync` and other assorted tools, like `tar`, `cpio`, `gzip` or `bzip2` a VERY simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync localdirectory backuphost:/remotepath/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "backup failed" | sendmail -t admin@example.com -s "backup failed"
fi
```

but that's just a ridiculously simple and non-complete example.

http://www.bacula.org/en/

http://www.amanda.org/

Comment: does rsync report a log if the sync failed? This was an example scenario that I described.Its not the only one and hence my question is a little broad in that sense. If people can describe enterprise scenario requirements alongwith the tools used to address them,it will be great

Answer (score 0):

One more excellent backup-software: [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sf.net/).

Answer (score 0):

dump/restore has worked for many years and still works great.